# DataSource.groovy classpath

Tags: grails, groovy, jenkins

```
def encryptedUid = getClass().getClassLoader()
                             .getResourceAsStream('user.txt')
                             .getText()
```

This code in the dataSource.groovy file works fine when I run it in a windows environment, but when I check the code in and Jenkins tries to load DataSource.groovy I get:

Error loading DataSource.groovy: Cannot invoke method getText() on null object.

The user.txt file is in the root of the src/java folder, and I know that it is built into the war file in a windows build. It just doesn't even get to building the war file on the Linux box.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @marko I guess he's trying to configure the database username and/or password, but doesn't want to put them in DataSource.groovy directly for security reasons. If so, there are better ways to do this...

Comment: I am trying to load the userid and password from encrypted strings in a file, along with a serialized SecretKey object. And @Donal, if there is a better way, I'm all ears. I cannot put the clear text password in the source code repository.

Comment: @GeorgeSmith see my update below

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're trying to configure the database username/password, but don't want to put them in `DataSource.groovy` directly for security reasons. Here's how I handle this:

Put the secret configuration in a file `/grails-app/conf/secret.properties`. The contents of this file are shown below:

```
dataSource.username=root
dataSource.password=secret
# other secret configuration
```

Include this file in the grails configuration by adding the following to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:secret.properties"]
```

If you want to be able to override the config. in `secret.properties` on a per-environment basis, change this to

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:secret.properties",
    "classpath:secret-${Environment.current}.properties"
]
```

You can then (optionally) add a file `secret-DEVELOPMENT.properties` that will override the configuration in `secret.properties` in the dev environment, and likewise for the other environments.

Of course, in order for this to work, the `secret*.properties` files must be present when building the war (or executing `run-app`) and should not be checked into VCS.

You're not restricted to placing these config. files in a relative location to the classpath. You can put them anywhere on the file system by using the `file:` prefix instead of `classpath:`. Finally, you can put the secret configuration in a `.groovy` config. file instead of a `.properties` file.

Comment: This makes no difference whatsoever

Comment: Thank you. That is better, but still not effective. I need the password to be encrypted. I use an encryption algorithm, then decrypt the password on the fly in the DataSourceConfig.groovy. The problem is finding the serialized SecretKey file that is needed for the decryption. The serialized SecretKey file is checked into source control along with the encrypted password and userid, and is on the classpath under windows, it's just not found there under linux.

Comment: If you store the encrypted password and the decryption key into source control, then what's the point in this exercise?